# static vector usage for Fibonacci series generation using recursion

Tags: c++, vector

I am a newbie in C++. I am trying to write a C++ program that generates Fibonacci series by effective use of recursion. The program I have written is as follows -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class FibonacciDynamic
{
private:
    static std::vector<int> memo(index);
    int index;
public:
    FibonacciDynamic(int a);
    int fib(int a);
    void display();
};

FibonacciDynamic::FibonacciDynamic(int a)
{
    index = a;
}

int FibonacciDynamic::fib(int a)
{
    if (a <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(memo.at(a-1) != 0)
    {
       return memo.at(a-1);
    }
    else
    {
        memo.at(a-1) = memo[a - 2] + memo[a - 3];
        return memo.at(a-1);
    }
}

void FibonacciDynamic::display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Generating Fibonacci series..." <<std::endl;
        std::cout << fib(i) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "Please, enter the index" << std::endl;
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    FibonacciDynamic f(a);
    f.display();
    return 0;
}
```

But, after compiling the code I am getting following errors -

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'index'
error C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

As all the errors are related with static vector that I've used, I think I have not declared it correctly; that's why compiler is not accepting it as vector & giving errors above. So, please help & guide me to correct way of vector usage in above code. Thanks.

Comment: Static data members exist before the class is instantiated. Initializing one with a per-object data member cannot possibly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static std::vector<int> memo(index);
int index;
```

I don't know what you expect that to do, but since `index` is not initialized, you certainly cannot use it to initialize `memo`.  What you have here will actually declare a static function (which I doubt is your intention).

Using a static vector for this is probably not the best route to take.  If you are looking to find the `N`th number in the Fibonacci sequence, you can use a vector member variable to store the intermediary values, or simply compute it each time.

Answer (score 2):

```
static std::vector<int> memo(index);
```

That declares a static member function `memo` taking a single (unnamed) argument of type `index` and returning a `std::vector<int>`.